# Is there a way to get the length of the returned value of enumerateFiles?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I'm trying to get an array of uri's but I don't know it's length when I create the array. The array length should be the length of the amount of items in the variable 'files'.
I know I can use a list to do this, but I want to try and streamline this to a single array, for which I need the length of 'files'

```
Uri[] imageArray = new Uri[*some amounts of items from 'files'*]
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\\Users\\doggoz\\Documents\\VisualStudio2015\\Projects\\somethinngggggg\\", "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                     .Where(s => s.EndsWith(".jpeg") || s.EndsWith(".jpg") || s.EndsWith(".png") || s.EndsWith(".gif") || s.EndsWith(".bmp"));
```

Comment: Not without enumerating twice, no.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `ToArray` method:

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\\Users\\doggoz\\Documents\\VisualStudio2015\\Projects\\somethinngggggg\\", "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                     .Where(s => s.EndsWith(".jpeg") 
                              || s.EndsWith(".jpg") 
                              || s.EndsWith(".png") 
                              || s.EndsWith(".gif") 
                              || s.EndsWith(".bmp")
                    ).ToArray();

var imageArray = new Uri[files.Length];
```

By the way I would suggest you change the multiple OR to something like the following, which makes your code more readable:

```
var extensions = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)  
{  ".jpeg", ".jpg", ".png", ".gif", ".bmp" };

var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Users\doggoz\Documents\VisualStudio2015\Projects\somethinngggggg\", "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                     .Where(s => extensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(s)))
                     .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your existing code, and just put the lines in the opposite order. That way you have the file enumeration ahead of time, and you can access the `Count()` method:

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(
    @"C:\Users\doggoz\Documents\VisualStudio2015\Projects\somethinngggggg\", 
    "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
        .Where(s => 
            s.EndsWith(".jpeg") || 
            s.EndsWith(".jpg") || 
            s.EndsWith(".png") || 
            s.EndsWith(".gif") || 
            s.EndsWith(".bmp"));

Uri[] imageArray = new Uri[files.Count()];
```

Or, you can just convert the results to a Uri array inline:

```
Uri[] imageArray = Directory.EnumerateFiles(
    @"C:\Users\doggoz\Documents\VisualStudio2015\Projects\somethinngggggg\", 
    "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
        .Where(s => 
            s.EndsWith(".jpeg") || 
            s.EndsWith(".jpg") || 
            s.EndsWith(".png") || 
            s.EndsWith(".gif") || 
            s.EndsWith(".bmp"))
        .Select(filePath => new Uri(filePath))
        .ToArray();
```